# Sum of a column with group by in django

Tags: mysql, django, django-rest-framework

I need some help with this sql query that I am trying to run with django orm model.

```
SELECT SUM(CAPITAL) AS PRODUCT_CAPITAL, PRODUCT FROM CAPITAL_SHEET
WHERE CLIENT_ID = 'X1234'
GROUP BY PRODUCT
```

I did this

```
CapitalSheet.objects.filter(client_id="X1234").values("product").annotate(Sum("capital"))
```

This is what I am getting as a result in json:

```
[
    {
        "product": "product1"
    },
    {
        "product": "product2"
    }
]
```

I was expecting this as output :

```
[
    {
        "product": "product1",
        "capital": 1234.00
    },
    {
        "product": "product2",
        "capital": 1234.00
    }
]
```

here is my view:

```
class CapitalListView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = CapitalSheetSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return CapitalSheet.objects.filter(client_id="X1234").values("product").annotate(Sum("capital"))
```

Here are my models:

```
class CapitalSheet(models.Model):
    log_id = models.AutoField(db_column='LOG_ID', primary_key=True)  
    client_id = models.CharField(db_column='CLIENT_ID', max_length=25)  
    capital = models.DecimalField(db_column='CAPITAL', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)  
    payout_booked_profit = models.DecimalField(db_column='PAYOUT_BOOKED_PROFIT', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)  
    voucher_number = models.CharField(db_column='VOUCHER_NUMBER', max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)  
    ledger_date = models.DateField(db_column='LEDGER_DATE', blank=True, null=True)  
    amount = models.DecimalField(db_column='AMOUNT', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)  
    product = models.CharField(db_column='PRODUCT', max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)  
    transaction_type = models.CharField(db_column='TRANSACTION_TYPE', max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)  
    sebi_payin_flag = models.IntegerField(db_column='SEBI_PAYIN_FLAG', blank=True, null=True)  
    dividend_payout_flag = models.IntegerField(db_column='DIVIDEND_PAYOUT_FLAG', blank=True, null=True)
```

My serializer:

```
class CapitalSheetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CapitalSheet
        fields = ['capital','product']
```

What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: how did your get the `json`? show code please

Comment: please add code of `CapitalSheetSerializer`

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try it, add name for annotate column:

```
CapitalSheet.objects.filter(
    client_id="X1234"
).values("product").annotate(capital=Sum("capital"))
#                            ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks, now i realize what I was doing wrong, I had tried this `.annotate(total=Sum("capital"))` , now i know that field name should be the same as the column name on which you are trying to calculate the sum.